# Issues in Google TTS in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, text-to-speech

Using Google TTS to developed in iPhone application, i have send a request in some words, then i get the audio data to play using AVAudioPlayer.

I have send a request as more words, then data comes as null. Google TTS supports only small kind of words to convert audio data or more, I want to know that so, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
NSString *linkTTS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=I+am+new+to+IPhone+development+I+am+working+on+Audio+player+i+have+to+show+the+current+time+and+estimated+time"];
    NSData *dataTTS = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkTTS]];
    NSLog(@"dataTTS:%@",dataTTS);
    _googlePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:dataTTS error:nil]; 
    [_googlePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

am also faced this problem i got help from this [link](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/) (right side of the link page contains 24.0 MB (download)file)may behelp for u

[fliteEngine stopTalking];// if u want to play text please commented this line in your code.

```
    [fliteEngine speakText:@"What ever you want to speech"];    // Make it talk
    [fliteEngine setPitch:100.0 variance:50.0 speed:1.0];   // Change the voice properties
    [fliteEngine setVoice:@"cmu_us_awb"];   // Switch to a different voice
    [fliteEngine stopTalking];// ignore the last line
```

happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Google TTS only works for short texts (under 100 characters).

So You have to manually split up the text related to your text length and provide the sub-texts to Google TTS.